# Through Hole Plated Pads

Tags: eaglecad

I recently made a small board in eagle (my computer wasn't able to run circuit maker) and I sent the board to be manufactured. It was a simples 2 layer PCB.

I noticed that the vias connecting top and bottom were OK, there was connection, but when I tried to check for continuity between the jtag connector and the microcontroller there was none (the JTAG connector is through hole and the microcontroller SMD and I connected them viathe top layer)

As you can see this is bad because I can't program my board unless I do some ugly jumpers, is there a way in eagle to do plated through hole pads for the pins of a connector?

Comment: The default PCB parts in Eagle have plated through holes, you have to go out of your way to specify holes without the through plating.  It sounds like your PCB fab didn't do plated through holes (this is pretty unusual).  Who was the PCB fab shop?

Comment: @DeanFranks It was a local one in Brazil ... near Porto Alegre to be more precise ... I thought that was weird because no through hole connectors has connection to the top (I tested it after I read your comment). Yep .. better change pcb manufacturer ... I didn't try PCBway or similar because this company used to be quite decent a few years ago, so I just assumed my error

Comment: How big are the via's? Could you fill them with solder?

Comment: @RonBeyer The vias are fine ... there is connectivity between top and bottom between them. The problem is in the pads for through hole components ... for example I routed the jtag on top layer and as it's a through hole component it' soldered at the bottom layer. The problem is that there is no connectivity between both layers in the "component holes" (forgot the word .. sorry)

Comment: Is there any way you can get to the pads on the top layer to apply solder to them (and the connector leads)? Might need to get clever for this one....

Comment: @DerStrom8 Yeah ... that's what I did. I just wanted to figure this problem out for when I send the new PCB for manufacturing. As of now it's working quite well if not for the jumpers I had to hand solder